# Matplotlib: How to make a plot using FOR loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I am trying to make a plot using .iterrows()

```
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    if rows['Country'] == 'France' and rows['Confirmed'] != 0:
        plt.plot(rows['Date'], rows['Confirmed'])
```

In result I am getting an empty plot.
What am I missing?

There are some data when I do:

```
df.loc[df['Country'] == 'France'].tail(2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHHDJ.png)

Comment: Hi @artyom-p . Please provide some sample data that we can easily copy. Also, please describe what's the expected output you want; is it a bar plot? a line chart? I've added my answer based on what I understand. If it's not what you need, please provide more details as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to plot a bar graph of the "Confirmed" column over time, but only for France.
If that's the case, then you don't need to use a For loop. Both Pandas and Matplotlib support operations on Series and lists.

One way to do what you need is:

```
# First, create a new dataframe that contains data of "France" and "Confirmed" > 0
france_confirmed_df = df[(df['Country'] == 'France') & (df['Confirmed'] != 0)]
# Then plot the bar plot using that new dataframe
plt.bar(france_confirmed_df['Date'], france_confirmed_df['Confirmed'])
```

I suggest you take a look at [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) and [Matplotlib's Pyplot tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html).